# Customizing Jira Embedded Widget

Tags: widget, jira

Is there any documentation or anywhere that notes how to customize the Jira Support Desk Embedded Widget behaviors? I want the widget to avoid asking a question and go straight to the Knowledge base and provide the customer with blank support desk ticket. Is this possible? How is it done?

Comment: For some context, I'm using Jira Cloud

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you ask a question, there is an expectation that you show some effort to solve a specific problem. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing or resource discovery service.

Comment: So far I've tried searching the Atlassian Developer forum, youtube as well as stack overflow and stack exchange for any documentation on how to customize the widget. I've looked through all the settings for the project as well as Jira itself. So far the only documentation I've found is on how to setup the widget. My coding knowledge is very basic and I assume it's a section of code that has to be omitted or redirected.